# XAML - Enable scrollviewer in tab item

Tags: wpf, xaml, scrollviewer

I added a scroll bar in a tab item, but the scroll bar is not enabled....  I can't figure out what I have done wrong...  Can someone point me in the right direction?  CanContentScroll is set to true....

Comment: Hi, can you post any code which demonstrates the problem? Is there any content to scroll?

Answer (score 2):

without code to see what you are attempting it's hard to know where you are going wrong...
However, should look something like:

```
<ScrollViewer  HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" >

<!-- content here -->

</ScrollViewer>
```

the scroll bars should become visible automatically, if the content increases beyond the size of the control the scrollviewer is placed within.